# Disable pre-populated file info comments in Xcode

Tags: xcode

As a beginner, this is of no use to me:

```
//
//  CarArrayController.m
//  CarLot
//
//  Created by X on 22/03/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//
```

It takes up unnecessary screen space. The first thing I do after creating a class is delete these lines manually. Is there a way to save me from this trouble?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `ios`, `objective-c` and `osx`

Comment: @Matt: I only tagged these 3, so that great coders of osx, ios and obj-c can see and comment on this. I know this is an XCode feature but most of us you xcode with these 3.

Comment: Strange how I get negative votes for asking a simple question! I am assuming they think the question is not well constructed. If I had the right words I would have found the answer via Google. Also, although it was answered before in this forum, my words "no info in xcode" did not bring it in the search results.....put yourself in a newbies' shoes, Sir.

Comment: Marking as a duplicate is not some kind of penalty; it's a time-saver. You've been helped by being given an explanation, a useful search term, a pointer to a tutorial, and a pointer to an existing StackOverflow discussion. Your question has been greatly improved by people editing it. I don't agree with the downvoting, but StackOverflow is a democratic, "wisdom of crowds" site. Don't play in this sandbox if you don't like the rules.

Comment: I had no problems with it being marked duplicate, (I was complaining about the down vote only). I was just saying that my "badly worded" subject did not show the duplicates in the search results and that I had made a sincere effort to browse through the search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a class, the files come from the file templates. You can modify them. Google something like "Xcode file templates". Here's an example:

http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/04/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/

Comment: Strange how I get negative votes for asking a simple question! I am assuming they think the question is not well constructed. If I had the right words I would have found the answer via Google. Also, although it was answered before in this forum, my words "no info in xcode" did not bring it in the search results.....put yourself in a newbies' shoes, Sir.

Comment: What's the point of your comment? I didn't downvote your question or vote to close it. I took your question seriously and answered it - and showed you how to learn more about the topic. Many others worked to improve your question, which was badly worded at the outset. You won't enjoy StackOverflow if you kick those who have given their time and effort to help you.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to tell YOU anything. I am satisfied with your answer. Infact, I chose yours as the best answer and also upvoted it. I had posted the comment here by mistake. I wanted to post it above like I did later. Somehow, I could not delete the comment posted here, I think.

Comment: Now, I see the delete "x" mark which appears only when I hover on the comment. I think I had tried "editing" earlier and edits with 0 words are probably not saved. Sorry again for the misunderstanding created due to placing the comment at the wrong place.